What is this type of radiating leaflet marker called?
Someone I work with pointed me to a website with a leaflet map with nested radiating point markers. The website is no longer available, so I cannot dive in to check what it was and how it was implemented, so I'm asking it here.
The main idea is that there are multiple point observations at the same location, so zooming in is not a solution. Therefore, when you click on the point marker, a new set of points pop up, from which you can select an individual point to show its attributes with a popup window. Like this:

Could anyone tell me what this type of radiating point marker is called in Leaflet and point me to some relevant documentation?

This is concept of marker clusters, where on lower zoom close by markers are grouped/combined into one cluster marker and individual markers are shown when you zoom in. Image on the right is consequence of clicking on marker cluster and showing individual markers in the so called "spiderified" form. See Leaflet.markercluster plugin.
